# programatic keydown event doesn't trigger event listener

Tags: jquery

I have an extension which adds an event listener to the window for `keydown`
I'm trying to manually trigger that event by doing something like:

```
var event = document.createEvent("Events");
event.initEvent("keydown", true, true);
event.view = document.defaultView;
event.keyCode = 9; 
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

The output in console is true but the extension doesn't respond at all.
The extension is also specifically checking the `keyCode` attribute and the TAB key(keyCode 9) is meant to 'activate' the extension. 
The problem comes from the dispatchEvent in my opinion and not from the event listener itself that's in the extension.

Any idea how to make this work?

Thank you!

Comment: Faking events programmatically is notoriously flaky. A better idea would be to just define your logic in a function and call it directly when needed.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I was going to put this in a function if it would have worked. The extension  is not made by me and therefore I don't want to edit it etc.